# How execute a user defined function automatically in an update?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this VBA function in an Excel 2003 sheet:

```
Function ContarColor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
    xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
            ContarColor = ContarColor + 1
        End If
    Next datax
End Function
```

I use the function to count the colors in a range.

For example I use:

```
=ContarColor(D4:AG5;Y31)
```

Where D4:AG5 is the range of rows, and Y31 is the referenced row color.

If I add or remove a color, and don't press enter in the formula, it does not refresh.

What can I do to automatically refresh on editing the range?

Comment: Use `Sub Worksheet_Change` with `Range(YourRange).Calculate`

Comment: @AntiDrondert, `Worksheet_Change` event handler doesn't get triggered by a cell color change

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly there is no default event which would trace cell color change (assuming that we are talking about normal formatting and not conditional formatting).  There are some workarounds, however require loops or Class module ([workarounds](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/574405-capturing-cell-color-change-vba.html)).

Additionaly, by default, UDF's (User Defined Functions) in Excel VBA are not volatile. If you try to add `Application.Volatile` at the begining of your function, you will see that after change of cell colour and pressing F9 (or any other change in the workbook) the function should recalculate.